# Flash .swf file not looping

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I have a .swf file that is not looping although I have added the parameter to do so. It plays just the once, and at the end of the video it stops instead of looping.
Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

```
       <div id="video">
          <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="211" height="316" id="FLVPlayer" style="visibility: visible; ">
            <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf">
            <param name="quality" value="best">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
            <param name="scale" value="noscale">
            <PARAM NAME="loop" VALUE="true"> 
            <param name="salign" value="lt">
            <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_2&amp;skinAutoHide=true&amp;streamName=ScreenOnlyDemo&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;loop=true">
            <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0">
            <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. -->
            <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
            <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="211" height="316">
              <!--<![endif]-->
              <param name="quality" value="best">
              <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
              <PARAM NAME="loop" VALUE="true">
              <param name="scale" value="noscale">
              <param name="salign" value="lt">
              <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_2&amp;skinAutoHide=true&amp;streamName=ScreenOnlyDemo&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;loop=true">
              <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0">
              <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
              <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
              <div>
                <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>

              </div>
              <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
          </object>
        </div><!-- video end -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what did you set in your Flash file (FLA). By default, a Flash file loops when it reaches the last frame.

FYI, to stop the loop, add a `stop();` in the ActionScript at the end frame. Valid for ActionScript 1-3.

Comment: +1 - as an example, if you have a 1-frame Flash file, it can't loop. Also, internal code overwrites the loop param in your embed. If there's a stop on frame 10, it'll stop and not pay attention to your param. btw - that param comes from the day when Flash was just an animation tool and is generally not used anymore.